# How to invoke a servlet at context root, welcome-file-list doesn't work

Tags: servlets

I'm new to MVC and I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.codejava.net/coding/jsp-servlet-jdbc-mysql-create-read-update-delete-crud-example). I'm having a hard time showing the records by default when the page loads. This is what I see with my current code

[image]

Both methods from my sevlet work, the insertUser and the listAllUsers methods, but listAllUsers is not being executed by default when the page loads.

How can I show the content automatically when the website first loads ?

This is my servlet

```
@WebServlet("/")
public class SvPeople extends HttpServlet {

    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public void init() {
        String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbpeople";
        String jdbcUsername = "root";
        String jdbcPassword = "1234";
        userDAO = new UserDAO(jdbcURL, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getServletPath();
        try {
            switch (action) {
                case "/insert":
                    insertUser(request, response);
                    break;
                default:
                    listAllUsers(request, response);
                    break;
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

    protected void listAllUsers(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
        List<User> listUser = userDAO.listUsers();
        request.setAttribute("listUser", listUser);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("list-users.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    private void insertUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws SQLException, IOException {
        String name = request.getParameter("name");

        User newUser = new User(name);
        userDAO.insertUser(newUser);
        response.sendRedirect("list-users.jsp");
    }
}
```

and this is the JSP I'm using

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Users</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My form!</h1>
        <c:forEach var="user" items="${listUser}">
            <ul>
                <li><c:out value="${user.id}"></c:out></li>
                <li><c:out value="${user.name}"></c:out></li>
                </ul>
        </c:forEach>


        <form action="insert" method="POST">

            Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
            <input type="submit" name="submit-button">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and lastly, I don't know if the issue comes from not having index.jsp as main page because I'm using a list-user.jsp as welcome file. Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="6.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SvPeople</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mycompany.crudtest.servlets.SvPeople</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SvPeople</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SvPeople</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>list-users.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know both methods work because when I submit a new user, it is added. I tested the listAllUsers  method by leaving it out of the switch-case. When I submit a new record, the records are shown in the website

Comment: Why do you need a welcom file? The tutorial is outdated. Find a newer tutorials.

Comment: thank you for answering. I removed it before and the app did not show anything. I will remove it and try again. Last time I tried was on wednesday and I had run the project many times. I will check if those multiple instances were interfering

Comment: How can you run it many times if it didn't work?

Comment: I modify the code, put print and breakpoints so I can debug it. You were right. I removed the welcome file from the web.xml and it ran. My guess is that the previous instances were somehow interfering. I had stopped the tomcat and undeployed multiple times. Thank you very much for your recommendation.

Comment: Did it work after you remove it? Post your pom.xml.

Comment: I posted it. Thanks

Comment: You have posted web.xml but I asked you to post pom.xml. It is used in the tutorial but they didn't publish complete file, so I can't read it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution as recommended in the comments was to remove the  from the web.xml.

```
<welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>list-users.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

This is how the web.xml looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="6.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SvPeople</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mycompany.crudtest.servlets.SvPeople</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SvPeople</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SvPeople</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: This is called Web Application Descriptor file. You have put a version 6.0 but your application code cannot run this version of servlet. The tutorial use version 3.1.